# Googlebot doesn't see jquery generated content

Tags: jquery, ajax, googlebot

I use jQuery to retrieve content from the database with a json request. It then replaces a wildcard in the HTML (like %title%) with the actual content. This works great and this way I can maintain my multi-language texts in a database, but Googlebot only sees the wildcards, not the actual content. I know Googlebot sees pages without javascript, but is there a way to deal with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give [this document](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992) at Google a thorough read.

It discusses how to enable Googlebot to index:

- pages where content changes depending on changing `#hashfragment` values in the URL.
- pages where content changes immediately upon load but lack any special `#hashfragment` per se.

In short, you're looking at adding the `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` as discussed in "step 3", and responding to special requests on the *server-side* by delivering back all the content all at once, that your client code otherwise would have generated after page load. These special requests are actually requests with `?_escaped_fragment_=...` in the URL, indicating to the server that it should pre-bake (my words) all of the final presentation into a single response for the Googlebot.

That said, since you'd be going through the effort of outputting filled in content for this special case, you may be better off doing that in your general case (avoiding the need to deal with Google's `_escaped_fragment_` requests), with perhaps still a way to swap out your markers after page load if necessary (e.g. through the use of spans with a certain `class` or `id` for identifying them).

Comment: I already use PHP for retrieving the data, so for the translations I now removed jQuery as in between and let PHP do the wildcard filling. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Google appears to have a near-fully or fully functional javascript-crawling bot at the time of this answer:

- In 2009 Google proposed a solution for making AJAX crawlable: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html
- In 2015 Google **deprecated** the above approach: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html
- I have successfully built multiple single page applications that are correctly rendered in Google's Webmaster tools.
- There are lots of resources on the web if you want to dive deeper:

  - http://searchengineland.com/can-now-trust-google-crawl-ajax-sites-235267
  - http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157
  - https://www.google.com/webhp?q=does+google+index+angular+single+page+apps

Comment: Thanks! `that are correctly rendered in Google's Webmaster tools` : do you mean it's possible to see how the page is rendered for GoogleBot? With which tool exactly?  Other remark : the main content of my website is loaded after 1) a google map is rendered on the page  2) an AJAX call imports the content.  Do you think this will work, or do you think the GoogleBot won't wait for 1) and 2) and will see my website as empty instead?

Comment: I have used google webmaster tools and it will capture what your site looks like and present it to you.  You have to Create an account and confirm you own the site.  It should wait for the map to load.  Once you have an account you can play around with webmaster tools.

Answer (score 0):

Googlebot obviously doesn't *render* the page that it downloads. This will probably be the same behavior that other search bots employ as well.

You need to use a server side scripting or compilation solution (there are plenty to choose from, including PHP, ASP.NET, etc). This way you still keep your dynamic and i18n features and Googlebot sees your page the way you intended. Or at least do this for fundamental page attributes like the Title that you know Googlebot is evaluating, and keep the jQuery updating for not so important parts of the page.

(To be honest though, using jQuery to replace tokens after the page has downloaded is probably not the most efficient way to do things, especially when server side scripting is so easy and free).