# SEO optimization for content generated by Javascript?

Tags: seo

I have created widgets for my website(xyz.com), which can be embedded in different websites. Let's say I embed a widget which is a photo album, in another website, abc.com. The content is residing on xyz.com but is pulled via Javascript into abc.com.

Will the content generated by the widgets (Javascript) on abc.com will be indexed by search engines?

Comment: possible duplicate of [google indexing text retrieved by ajax or javascript after page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211257/google-indexing-text-retrieved-by-ajax-or-javascript-after-page-load)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google will not index anything that is not visible when a page is loaded with JavaScript disabled.

There is more information in this similar question: 
[google indexing text retrieved by ajax or javascript after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211257/google-indexing-text-retrieved-by-ajax-or-javascript-after-page-load)

Also, you can test what Googlebot 'sees' by using the "Fetch as Googlebot" feature of [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools).

If you *want* Google to index your Ajax, you can read Google's recommendations here:
http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: @ethanphil  And what about widget like disqus? How can I do it when I don't have access to server-side? Is it possible to make html snapshots and index it in the customer domain?

Answer (score 2):

If you follow Google's scheme for [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/), then Google will index content that's generated with Javascript. So will Bing and Yandex.

Implementing this scheme is somewhat involved which is why there are companies that provide it as a service that plugs in at webserver level. (I work for one of these: https://ajaxsnapshots.com