# Workaround for JavaScript generated sites with search engines: will it work?

Tags: javascript, html, seo, search-engine, dynamic-content

I have an issue with my site. It is primarily JavaScript generated, and the JavaScript is very complex. Therefore, most search engines won't be able to pick up the data of the website because it is created by JavaScript. The closest thing to a "fix" i have thought of is to have an invisible element at the bottom of the page, and some server-side stuff that fills this in with the textual content. Hopefully, the user won't be able to see this element and the search engine will, therefore solving my issue.

But, I'm worried that search engines might see this as being too similar to the system where crazy people put the same keyword many times in invisible elements in an attempt to get higher rankings. Will the search engine pick this up as that hack because the element is invisible? Or will it work fine? I don't care about those thousands of search engines that nobody uses, just Google, Bing, and Yahoo.

Another REALLY crude method I'm pretty sure wouldn't work is to just dump everything into the `meta` `description` tag. But if that would work, please tell me

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Duplicate post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885710/seo-optimization-for-content-generated-by-javascript

Comment: that's asking if it crawls JS. I know it doesn't. I'm asking if my workaround will work or if it will be viewed as invalid and my site will be banned from google

Comment: hmm...seems to already be some stuff here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547426/google-seo-and-hidden-elements

Comment: In short: It can, but it doesn't load external scripts (even from the same domain). Source: http://moz.com/ugc/can-google-really-access-content-in-javascript-really

Comment: What do you mean by "it can"? Do you mean that "it can" see this as being a hack and ban my site? Do you mean that "it can" work? What exactly do you mean?