# Dynamic META tags in HTML5 and Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, seo

we are developing a corporate website, where all the navigation is done using hashs (`http://xxx/#/content/xpto`), and the content is dynamically loaded using AJAX. The role stuff is already working fine, and we are getting good results from it. The question (or issue) I have is this, as the navigation is completely done using hashs and no page load (URI change) is actually present, we are changing the "META" tags (*using something like `$('meta[property="title"]').attr('content', metainfo.title);`) in the code. Does **Google's SEO engine or Facebook's page runtime**, can understand this meta changes made by the code, i.e. `http://myurl.com/#/load/products`, or the content is analysed by processing the HTML content from the server (*html stuff* `<html><head>blah blah blah</head></html>`)?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885710/seo-optimization-for-content-generated-by-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can't do dynamic meta tags (or well, you can, but Google and Facebook won't run your JavaScript so they won't do you any good), but you can follow [Google's guide for making AJAX applications crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?csw=1). I don't know if Facebook has a similar guide.

Comment: Thanks ox, but again this is just part of the solution. Unfortunately, very complex JS pages are difficult to index and generate HTML snapshots as Google requested. I'm writing a indexing service in the server using chromium C++ API, as Chrome was the only solution I was nearly near of getting the role thing done (successfully generate HTML snapshots for complex JS processing). Anyways, if you have any remarks or ideas that could help, please talk to me.

Comment: The Google guide link in the answer is officially deprecated

Comment: This entire is now out of date.  Google most certainly runs JavaScript now, and will even pay attention to dynamically created meta tags.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can use JS to change the meta tags dynamically, as mentioned in this post:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/javascript-seo-basics#titles-and-snippets

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is struggling with the same problem that I was, the answer is not quite simple. Unfortunately, for situations where the page is created using complex JS processes, the most common "**headless**" browsers in the market (including the one's Google recommends - *HtmlUnit, watiji or Crawjax*) don't do the trick.

The solution I found wasn't very elegant, but it worked. I've implemented a C++ indexing service using http://www.awesomium.com/. They have a very straightforward solution based on Google's chromium API. Of Course, a few "**JS**" animations had to be removed, but anyways, the HTML snapshots are being generated as expected.

> Solution flow:
>
> 1. Created a **sitemap**;
> 2. Made the indexing service (*using Awesomium*) read and generate a HTML snapshot for every page defined in the **sitemap** file;
> 3. The files (*HTML snapshots*) were saved in a secure location in the server, with the same directory structure and file name defined in
>      the browser URL;
> 4. Created a Servlet (we are using Java EE) to read the **HTML snapshots** requested by Google's indexing drone: *the
>      "**?_escaped_fragment_=**" querystring parameter*.

A detail information on how to construct full crawler drones for Google can be found here (as OX stated - thx): https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started