# meta dynamic with javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, share

I need to make dynamic meta.
on click or on load the page, the field of metatags have to take the content inside tag <h1>.
it's possible?

```html
<html>
  <head> 

    <title>my site</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="" />

  </head>
  <body>

    <h1 id="titolo">Titolo</h1>

    <p id="descrizione">Vestibulum velit justo, porta a aliquet a; sodales nec quam. Etiam lobortis tortor ex, non iaculis dolor interdum in!</p>

    <img id="immagine" src="immagine.jpg" />

    <a target='_blank' class="fb"href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://miosito.org/' >Share facebook</a>
    <a target='_blank' class="tw" href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://miosito.org/ '>Share twitter</a>
    <a target='_blank' class="gplus" href='https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://miosito.org/' >Share gplus</a>

  </body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: what is the use of adding meta tag after page load??

Comment: So you want to be able to get the content attribute of the meta tag? If so what will you do with it?

Comment: Why have you left all the closing `'`s? @manu

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use javascript to change the meta-tags of the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page)

Comment: Ciao @GiacomoPaita
in pratica voglio che i campi dei meta vengano popolati in base al contenuto della pagina. Esempio il meta title (<meta property="og:title" content="" />) deve prendere il contenuto dal tag <h1>

Comment: Capito: vedi che user3443313 ti ha risposto correttamente. usa $('meta[property="og:title]"') per prendere assegnare il valore che vuoi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this with jQuery try this:

```
$('meta[property=og:title]').attr('content', 'new content');
```

where 'new content' is the content you wish to place inside it.

Edit:
To do exactly what you want to do and set the content to what's in the H1 you might try:

```
$('meta[property=og:title]').attr('content', $('#titolo').html());
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('meta[property=og:title]').attr('content', $('#titolo').html());
 });
</script>

I've tried but don't work

Comment: $('meta[property="og:title]"'), but I do not think that it makes sense your question, because, when you update the tag og, facebook has already parsed the page with the actual value, not the replaced, as @Guruprasad Rao mentions in the comment.

Comment: See here, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127891/dynamic-meta-tags-in-html5-and-javascript-jquery?rq=1

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('meta[property="og:title"]').attr('content', $('#titolo').html());
 });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

It's been answered before but you could do something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('meta[property=og:title]').remove();
    $('head').append('<meta property="og:title" content="blah" />');
});
</script>
```