# Adding/updating meta tags not working in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I imported a [Meta](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta#meta) Service in `AppModule`

But it is not working. I hooked a method containing my `meta.updateTag()`'s into the Router's NavigationEnd event.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
        .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .map(() => this.route)
        .map((route) => {
            while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
            return route;
        })
        .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
        .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
        .subscribe((event) => {
            console.log('NavigationEnd:', event);
            this.updateDescription(event['description'], event['keywords'],
                event['title']);
        });
}
updateDescription(desc: string, keywords: string, title: string) {
    this.titleService.setTitle(title);
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: desc })
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'keywords', content: keywords })
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:title', content: title })
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'og:description', content: desc })
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'not working'? Do you have any errors?

Comment: There is no any error displaying but dynamic content is not fetching and it only displaying meta tag from index.html

Comment: Hi @NileshKumar, Please elaborate your target goal and show an example output of your desire, the purpose of the your added snippet, add a snippet also that shows your import to the `AppModule`, show also the dependecy injection to the constructor of your Component, Show also what is the current output of your current code.

Comment: @ColdCerberus I can see that url,title,and description and all meta tag displaying in browser inspection but i am not able to post using linkedin and twitter share button.

Comment: @ColdCerberus In my requirement i want to update metatags content through dynamically. content was updated successfuly in INSPECT ELEMENT but i didn't see updated content in view source page. i want to update metatags in view source page also through dynammic. please help me to solve this requirement. i need to update metatags in view source page

Comment: @NileshKumar Do you mean that you are able to change the metatags on runtime but your problem is how to save the current change permanently so that it will persist in the current url shared and show the correct thumbnails and other descriptions?

Comment: Not an expert to SEO's, meta tags and such. But I believe that dynamic meta tags will not work to most (if not all) websites. According to this answer from another post, FB and Google won't run your javascript (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29127965/2678218)

Comment: @ColdCerberus yes sir how to save current changes permanently so that it will persist in current URL

Comment: actually i want to apply social share button like twitter,linked In in our Angular 6 website.i can see dynamic URL,title etc in inspect element but not show details when social share button is clicked.

Comment: @ColdCerberus my facebook social share is working fine, i need others like LinkedIn and Twitter with image sharing.

Comment: @NileshKumar can you please update your question with more details? And please include the necessary parts that made it work for facebook.

Answer (score 2):

According to [OG documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters?locale=ru_RU) you should use `property` attribute instead of `name`.

```
updateDescription(desc: string, keywords: string, title: string) {
  this.titleService.setTitle(title);
  this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: desc })
  this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'keywords', content: keywords })
  this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: title })
  this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: desc })
}
```

Please make sure there are the same `property` names in your index.html file.

Answer (score -2):

Done a quick research to help out. According to [Manuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827148/manuel)'s anwer in [Angular 4 - Update Meta tags dynamically for Facebook (Open graph)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48120752/2678218)
.

> Open Graph OG Tags must be within the sourcecode! You need to provide
> a static html page containing the the open graph tags like og:image
> og:title and og:description in the html sourcecode, since facebook,
> twitter and co a just scraping the plain html without rendering it
> through javascript. Angular dynamically updates the dom through js and
> therefore the crawlers just get the initial index.html.
>
> There are several ways to serve an html containing open graph tags ans
> solve your issue:
>
> - Serverside rendering with angular universal
> - use an proxy rendering your page
> - overwriting index.html on the fly replacing og tags
> - serving static html pages (not sure if this is supported by angular)

And from another thread, [Social websites are not showing updated meta tags on share?](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17331), [Toxicable](https://account.microsoft.com/profile/) also recommended using **Angular Universal** ([see here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17331#issuecomment-307072576)) to be able to facilitate web crawlers (SEO).

See [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) to learn more.

You can also try doing it the way [sathishcharykotha](https://github.com/Sathishchary) described their solution on the same thread. [See here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17331#issuecomment-363695409)

> We are not using angular universal for now, we ended up this issue with creating simple spring web application, we are just sending meta tags from client application to simple web application, there we are generating new url and from that we will redirect to angular app. But this is not good idea. We are looking to change this to angular universal. thanks