# How to insert specific strings from page into meta tags with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags, page-title

I need this for SEO purposes. A small amount of pages on the website I'm working on, get generated dynamically, but their meta data is very generic - even though 5 of theses (different) pages have relatively different content, they will have the same title and description, which I'm trying to avoid.

I want to insert specific content from a page, into it's meta tags via JavaScript.

The page looks something like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>This is the current title i want to replace</title>
  <meta name="description" content="This is the current description i want to replace.">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Post Title</h1>
  <div class="intro">
    <p>Intro text goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>More content</p>
    <p>Even more content</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm looking to inject the content of:

> ".intro" ("Intro text goes here" in this example) -> into the meta description of the page`

and

> "h1" ("Post Title" in this example) -> into the meta title of the page

to make the end result look something like this:

```
<head>

<title>Post Title</title>

<meta name="description" content="Intro text goes here.">

</head>
```

As my JavaScript skills are limited, this is the only way i managed to change the page's title and meta descritpion for now:

```
document.title = "Post Title";
document.getElementsByTagName('meta')["description"].content = "Intro text goes here.";
```

Obviously this is too static for the purpose, and doesn't pull any data from the content of the page.

How do i amend the two lines of code above, in order for it to inject the desired strings into the meta title and description?

Comment: I'm not sure i follow you on this one? Are you saying spiders will read the original title/description, before the JavaScript changes it to the desired output? 

I need this for SEO purposes. A small amount of pages on the website i'm working on, get generated dynamically, but their meta data is very generic - even though 5 of theses (different) pages have relatively different content, they will have the same title and description, which i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I would focus on doing this server side not in Javascript. You mention needing this for SEO purposes. The spiders most likely won't even see your javascript updates.

Comment: What platform did you use to make the website?

Comment: @mplungjan The reason for why I'm looking to go down this route is that I have succesfully injected/changed canonical data with this code on another website of mine: "var pageURL = jQuery(location).attr("href"); jQuery('link[rel="canonical"]').attr('href',pageURL);", which gets picked up perfectly fine by Google and other "test canonical" tools out there.

Comment: @mplungjan It's not whine - it's just frustration, as i don't know how to ask the questions better than I already did. And the downvotes caused StackOverflow to promt me with a warning, that I might get blocked from asking questions, if i get more downvotes.

Comment: @imvain2 I see. Doing this on the server side is even more out of my reach. As stated in one of my comments above, I know Google is crawling (and respecting) canonical URL's that i injected via jQuery on another website i've build, so i hoped this would work as well. It's on a WordPress install by the way.

Comment: You can delete your previous comments. I have added the pertinent one to the question and the rest of the comments to me are no longer relevant. Keep the discussion with imvain

Comment: @emiliano85 wordpress should have the ability to have custom meta tags. if not, I know there are plugins that give you that ability.

Answer (score 1):

I'll avoid commenting on best SEO practices (since the comments address this pretty well) and just address the code part of your question.

You just need to reference that `meta` element and adjust the `content` attribute.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Post Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Intro text goes here.">
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <!-- Keep this <script> just prior to the closing body tag.
         so that it runs after all the page HTML is parsed. -->
    <script>
      // Get a reference to the meta element:
      const meta = document.querySelector("meta[name='description']");
      
      console.log(meta);  // For testing
      meta.content = "Something new";  // Set this to whatever value you need.
      console.log(meta);  // For testing      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this, at least Google will spider your page with a headless browser that respects JS

[Webmaster: does inserting meta elements into the head using js effect seo](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137465/does-inserting-meta-elements-into-the-head-using-js-effect-seo)

[Dynamic META tags in HTML5 and Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127891/dynamic-meta-tags-in-html5-and-javascript-jquery)

you can do this to change the description. It is however recommended to do all SEO preparations on the server

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>This is the current title i want to replace</title>
  <meta name="description" content="This is the current description i want to replace.">
  <script>
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // the rest of the page has loaded
    const metaDesc = 
    document.querySelector("meta[name=description]")
    metaDesc.content = document.querySelector(".intro p").textContent;
    console.log(metaDesc.outerHTML); // show the tag for testing purposes
  })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Post Title</h1>
  <div class="intro">
    <p>Intro text goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>More content</p>
    <p>Even more content</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `meta` tags don't have any `textContent` as they are empty elements.